# Generate warning on using method returning value without modifying it's object

Tags: c#

Is there any possibility to create function, like string.trim() which return some kind of value and do not modify it's object, which will generate warning when we do not assign it's return value to proper object?

Is there any attribute that i could attach to the method to do that?

Comment: Well, yes and no. You can attach the [PureAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.contracts.pureattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to something. Depending on code analysis however you may or may not get a warning about this.

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: @Evk I am using Productivity Power Tools 2015.

Comment: Was asking because resharper has code annotations and among them there are 2 attributes which does exactly what you want (resharper will produce a warning if a return value of method decorated with such attribute is not used).